# Clearing multiple Textbox controls on button click

Tags: asp.net, textbox

-I have a form with plenty of textboxes.
-When I click "clear" i'd like them all to reset or have their .Text value set to " "; . I'd   prefer not to have to write "  (Textbox1.text=""; ) " 14 or 15 times.
-Please don't make it any more difficult than it needs to be.
-I'm using asp.net 4.5.

Comment: Are you wanting the clear to be client side only or do you want it to do a postback and clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created two textboxes Textbox1 and Textbox2. Below is the code to clear them.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var tbs = new List<TextBox>() {TextBox1,TextBox2 };
        foreach(var textBox in tbs)
        {
            textBox.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this handy method that enumerates all child controls of specified type on some parent control, no matter if they are on some container control deeper in hierarchy :

```
public List<T> FindControl<T>(Control holder) where T : Control
{
  var result = new List<T>();
  foreach (Control control in holder.Controls)
  {
    if (control is T)
      result.Add(control as T);
    result.AddRange(FindControl<T>(control));
  }
  return result;
}
```

So in your case you can get all controls in `Page_Load` :

```
var pageTextBoxes = FindControl<TextBox>(this);
```

if you do that in `Page_Load`, then this is current Page and you will get all Text Boxes on page, so just clear it :

```
  foreach (var txtControl in pageTextBoxes)
  {
    txtControl.Text = "";
  }
```

If you want some more conditions, for example if TextBox ID starts with LeftControl :

```
  foreach (var txtControl in pageTextBoxes.Where(tx => tx.ID.StartsWith("LeftControl")))
  {
    txtControl.Text = "";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through all the controls on the page and clear those which are textboxes. Something like this might help you get started:

```
public void ClearTextBoxes(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        if ((c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)))
        {
            // Clear the text box
            ((TextBox)(c)).Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

So you could just call this function on your button click.

```
ClearTextBoxes(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take one of the following 2 approaches:

1. add a html reset button, clicking the button will automatically reset values to last values

see it here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_reset

1. The first will not work after postback but you can use javascript do that instead of writing server side code. Use following method and pass your form or you can change it to accordingly.

http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-reset-form.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you cannot get all webcontrols in a page, so use Request.Form you can get all controls and clear the controls(Sure this might help you)

```
 public void ClearTextboxes()
    {
        foreach (string control in Request.Form.AllKeys)
        {
            Control pageControl = Page.FindControl(control);
            if (pageControl is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox textBox = (TextBox)pageControl;
                textBox.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt= new List<TextBox>() {TextBox1ID,TextBox2ID };
    foreach(var textBox in txt)
    {
        textBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
```

This might help